# Configuration parameter in xdebug for allowing multiple hosts on remote machine

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, zend

I am working on one web application. The project located on my linux box i.e. server. We are remotely accessing this machine from windows.

I am using xdebug for debugging alongwith Eclipse PDT. xdebug is installed on my server. Below configuration are set in php.ini file ( which is located on server ) :

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=10.88.36.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug.log
```

After doing the above configuration setting in php.ini for xdebug, its allowing only one host this time ( i.e. 10.88.36.1)

Here my question is I wanted to allow for multiple hosts. I know in zend debugger there is one configuration parameter present which does this i.e.

```
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=10.88.36.28, 10.88.36.1
```

Whether this parameter present in xdebug ? so that i can able to allow multiple hosts to have access to server remotely.

Thanks,

-Pravin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://derickrethans.nl/debugging-with-multiple-users.html set up a DGP proxy..

Answer (score 3):

xdebug also supports multiple hosts you have to set remote_host setting like following

```
xdebug.remote_host=10.88.36.28, 10.88.36.1
```

I have used only one host at a time without changing the host in .ini hope it will help.